# steps for facebook connect graph api

Tags: php, facebook

iam using facebook connect in my site, and i want to know how do i use the graph api for authenticating the user. I followed these steps:

1) Initially i sent a request for "code", by clicking on the facebook icon in my site:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://xxxxxxxx

2) And then after getting a code, i sent a request for "access token", by clicking on another link in my site:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://xxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxx&code=xxxxx

3) And after i got the token, i sent another request for getting user data, by clicking on yet another link:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Then finally i got the user data in array format, which i need to parse for my required data like user's firstname, email, etc.

Now my question is that how i can automate this process with just one click ?
Right now, iam using 3 different links for sending those requests.

Can anyone suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip these hassles, use **Facebook JavaScript SDK**. It provides all the core functionality for authenticating Facebook users. Load the JS SDK using your `APP ID` by `FB.init()` method. Then for user-login or extended permissions, you can use `FB.Login()` and likewise. It will take care of all `OAuth` communication, which you were doing by-hand. More information at

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/javascript
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Meanwhile, When i got the user data as an array format, how do i extract the user's individual data values from it? Please specify. I got the user data in this format: 

stdClass Object ( [id] => xxxxxxx [name] => xxxxxxxxxx [first_name] => xxxxx [last_name] => xxxxxxxx [link] => xxxxxxxxx [birthday] => xx/xx/xxxx [hometown] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 104095059626102 [name] => xxxxxx ) [location] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 115200305158163 [name] => Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh ) [bio] => xxxxx [quotes] => xxx [gender] => male [email] => xxxx..... )

Comment: Facebook responses are JSON objects. Hence, these are basic JS Objects. You can look here  for some help : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.api/

Comment: I could not get it work... i thought i got a php array in json format.. but is there any other means of fetching this data ?

Comment: Thanks anyways, i could get the user data using: $user->email, $user->name, etc., where $user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx'));

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Facebook API for that:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Look at the example on that website for more information.

Answer (score 1):

maybe quicker to use the official facebook implementation for php - you can find it here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk